# ZSI.generate.Wsdl2PythonError: unsupported local simpleType restriction

Tags: python, xml, soap, zsi

i have this simple type from an external webservice:

```
<xsd:element name="card_number" maxOccurs="1"
minOccurs="1">
<xsd:simpleType>
    <xsd:restriction base="tns:PanType">
        <xsd:pattern value="\d{16}"></xsd:pattern>
        <xsd:whiteSpace value="collapse"></xsd:whiteSpace>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:element>
```

but whe i launch wsdl2py -b filename.wsdl i got this error:

```
ZSI.generate.Wsdl2PythonError: unsupported local simpleType restriction: <schema targetNamespace="https://xxxxx.yyyyy.zz/sss/"><complexType name="PaymentReq"><sequence><element name="card_number"><simpleType>
```

How can i fix this? I tried to change from simpleType to compleType and wsdl2py generate python code without problem. In this way i can't be able to use card_number in my python object.

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still the case, but a quick google suggests that simpleTypes with user-defined restriction bases aren't supported by ZSI.

If this is still the case, then you could modify the restriction for "card_number" to remove the base and update the restriction-facets within the simpleType-restriction to reflect what the base would have provided.

If you post the content of restriction facets for `PanType`, we can tell you what that would be.

Comment: Thank for your response! If i change this line 
<xsd:restriction base="tns:PanType"> with this <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"> it works, but it changes data type.
I don't know Pantype's content, because it stays on external server: xmlns:tns="https://xxx.yyy.it/sss/"
How do you modify above element?

Thank you.

Comment: You should be able to resolve `PanType`, is it not referenced by a `location` definition?

Comment: Nop! The locations that i see on wsdl file are location of "service" tag. This wsdl is provided by a bank and i ask them PanType definition. I'm not confident in them positive response. :-|

Comment: Obviously, I'm not seeing the whole picture, but if what you say is true: that you have no access to the schema definition for `PanType` then I don't see how you could be expected to produce valid elements with restrictions based on it.

Comment: Exactly! I hope that the bank give me definition of PanType.
Thank you very much, for now! :)

Comment: Bank told me to use xsd:string and ignore Pantype.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: You're very welcome! You might want to gently suggest to them that including dependencies to private documents in "published" API's isn't particularly helpful.